# .net Google.Cloud.Firestore name resolution error in grpc

Tags: .net, dns, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

My backend fails on trying to access cloud firestore collection. I use the nuget package Google.Cloud.Firestore (currently 1.0.0-beta20).
The error says

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Name resolution failure")
```

My code is

```
public async Task PushAppointment(CcAppointment appointment)
{
    var fireStoreDb = await FirestoreDb.CreateAsync("peakplan-fb-mobile"); 

    var docRef = fireStoreDb.Collection("appointments");  
    await docRef.AddAsync(appointment);
}
```

Google Credentials JSON env var is correctly setup and loaded.

I get these logs prior to the exception message:

```
D0530 02:26:56.253562 Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary Attempting to load native library "/Users/gabrielwahle/.nuget/packages/grpc.core/1.19.0/lib/netstandard1.5/../../runtimes/osx/native/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.dylib"
D0530 02:26:56.347160 Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension gRPC native library loaded successfully.
```

with these log settings:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GRPC_TRACE", "api,cares_resolver,cares_address_sorting");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GRPC_VERBOSITY", "debug");
```

Has anyone dealt with that error before?